# transform-builtin-extend seems does not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-class

I have an error with transplied class:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

at Form.ExtendableBuiltin (http://local.yandex.ru:30002/bundle.js:79395:14)
at new Form (http://local.yandex.ru:30002/bundle.js:79422:103)
```

My .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "latest"],
    "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-syntax-decorators",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy",
        ["babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend", { // Class Extending Natives
            globals: ["FormData"],
            approximate: true
        }],
        "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
        // "syntax-async-functions",
        // "transform-async-to-generator",
        // "transform-regenerator",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-rebem-jsx",
        "transform-es2015-typeof-symbol"
    ],
}
```

My class:

```
import map from 'lodash/map'

export default class Form extends FormData {
    constructor (data) {
        super()
        map(data, (val, key) => this.append(key, val))
    }
}
```

A piece of transpiled code:

```
function _extendableBuiltin(cls) {
    function ExtendableBuiltin() {
        cls.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

Where `cls` is `FormData`.

Expected something like this:

```
function _extendableBuiltin(cls) {
    return function ExtendableBuiltin() {
        return new cls(arguments);
    }
```

babel --version
6.14.0 (babel-core 6.14.0)

webpack --version
Version: webpack 1.13.2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `FormData` is extensible.

Comment: @Bergi In Firefox and Chrome `new class MyFormData extends FormData {}` works fine.

Comment: It should work for `approximate: false`, `approximate: true` simulates the behavior from Babel 5, but Babel 5 also would have failed in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `approximate` option to `false`. From [the plugin GitHub repository](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend):

> On older browsers that do not support reassigning the prototype of an existing object, you will need to enable the approximate mode, which will fall back to the Babel 5 behavior of using simple ES5 inheritance to `approximate` extending a class, though your results may vary depending on your goals.